# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Converting string to ASCII

Tags: java, ascii, numberformatexception

I am trying to convert my **string to ASCII** value through my hash function, which looks like this:

```
    public long hash(String word){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String ascString = null;
    long asciiInt;
    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
        sb.append((int)word.charAt(i)); 
    }
    ascString = sb.toString();
    asciiInt = Long.parseLong(ascString);
    return asciiInt;        
    }
```

and later on, I will call it in my insert() method to perform quadratic hashing using a **hashTable**, and the insert method looks like this:

```
    public void insert(Word word){
    int start = (int)(hash(word.text)%tableSize);
    int key = start;
    int attempt=0;
    while(hashTable[key]!=null){
        attempt++;
        key=(start+(int)Math.pow(attempt,2))%tableSize;
    }
    hashTable[key]=word;    
    }
```

However, it throws the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if the string I am trying to convert has more than 6 characters. Can anyone help me fix it or a better ways of coming up with the key value for my hash table?

Thanks!

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense.  What is the purpose?

Comment: Look at the actual *value* that results in the NFE. Work backwards from there. Attaching a debugger and stepping through the code would be very .. enlightening.

Comment: Why not use a HashMap?

Comment: If you look at the value in `ascString`, it will have at least twice as many digits (maybe three times as many) as there were characters in the input string.  A `long` can contain about 19 decimal digits.  If you're entering lower-case letters it will only take 7 letters to blow the limit.

Comment: Note that String has a very good `hashCode` function.

Comment: (What you're calling an "ASCII value" is nothing of the sort.)

Comment: For this project, we are specified to not use the hashCode method. Is there an easier way to come up with the hashCode maybe?

Comment: ascii is 8-bit, so use an 8-bit type for your conversion.  Unless your string is all numeric, you cannot parse it to long.

Answer (score -1):

The value you're attempting to gain (base 10 long) can't be achieved from your string because you've the wrong base. Say the string is "DEADBEEF". Because all digits of DEADBEEF are base 16, you can specify the radix as 16 and use

```
 Long.parseLong(DEADBEEF, 16);
```

The non-radix method assumes that the string contains a base-10 long when really the number is much longer (DEADBEEF is 3735928559 in base 10). Check your string maybe?

Comment: are you assuming the string was originally a hex string or something?

Comment: Just any base that, when parsed from `String` type, couldn't be stored into a long. Like, if there's an 'h' in the string, it's at least base-18. Check out `BigInteger`

Comment: so you recommend changing the base depending on the predicted contents of an unknown string?

Comment: I don't know what's in your string. Just trying to help